# Blocking Cuss/Vulgar/Obscenity Terms in PHP

Tags: php, filter, words

I know you might laugh, but actually this is a common need in most apps. Many apps that take in customer/visitor input may need to filter cuss words or vulgar terms.

Sometimes PHP changes and new stuff gets added in. For instance, just the other day I learned about MultiCurl API in PHP5. So, anyway, is there a new native function in PHP that lets me filter most common English-based cuss words in a string, as well as flip a boolean to say, "string had English-based cuss words in it"? It doesn't need to be perfect, obviously, but cut out a good bit of garbage and let me replace it with ### for instance.

If that's not part of PHP yet, then does anyone have a function that I can use which cloaks the cuss word list? For instance, I want it such that I can drop the class in a project and not have to worry about another programmer getting offended. In other words, a decently encoded cuss word list -- not one actually spelled out.

Now, obviously it needs to be flexible and let words like "rebuttal" get through.

**tl;dr**: **Does PHP5 now have a native function that can filter obscene words? And if not, does anyone have a class that encodes a cuss word list so that it doesn't offend other programmers?**

Comment: Please clarify your post to make it obvious what your programming question is.

Comment: @Gabe Clarified enough for you?

Comment: IMO you're trying to be non-offensive to the point of being offensive. ;o)

Comment: @deceze Please be more clear. How can I serve you better?

Comment: IMO bad word filters are the wrong approach to begin with. If your audience is that immature, you're just fighting an uphill battle. Human intervention works better IMO, it should be about shaping the community, not about censoring words. But be that as it may, even withholding the bad word list from your own programmers takes it a bit far. *Somebody* will have to look at the list.

Comment: Imagine a coupon site. You get all kinds of people there -- good, bad, etc. Sure, I could have a Reddit-like +/- review of comments so that ones with cuss words might get down-modded, but I was looking for an easier out. As for shielding from other programmers, read my comments to @Patrick in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is something that would be a high priority for the core PHP team since that treads dangerously close to censorship.  Censorship in that they would have a 'master' list of 'inappropriate' language which should be filtered.

You can do this fairly simply.  Make up an array of all the words you want filtered out and when a page is displayed that contains user input run a `preg_filter()` on the words.

$bad_words = array('bleeping', 'blooping');
$submitted_text = 'bleh blah....';

echo preg_filter($bad_words, $replace, $submitted_text);

Note: you will have to deal with the edge cases where a bad word might be inside of a good word (i.e.- 'shitzu[sic] dog')

**EDIT**
For the bad-words-inside-good-words issue, you can add to the regular expression to require space at the beginning and end of the bad word.  If you have lots of submissions though, it's going to be a constant battle to keep up with the trolls.

Comment: Yes, obviously that's the technique. Three things, though. One is coming up with a list -- I really don't like coming up with a list of common English cuss words. 'Was hoping someone already had that. Two is that I need a class that has the cuss words encoded so that, when dropped into a project, it doesn't offend some programmers. Three is that you are right -- I have to handle edge cases with an 80/20 rule, as well as handle cases where the word may not be encased in spaces, but may have some kind of punctuation right next to it. See how tough this is?

Comment: #1 - I did a quick google search and found this: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial163_Foul-language-filter-in-PHP.html  That appears to work well.  #2 - I'm sorry, but programmers should not be offended by just happening to see a list of bad words, especially in the context of filtering those words out from the public.  Although the solution I just linked to allows the programmers to not be required to view the list since it's in a separate, obvious, file.

Comment: I'll go with your answer. However, I found a function I had not used before called str_rot13() which lets me rapidly munge up some cuss words back and forth so as not to be easily viewed. I have to admit that I worked with a female Indian programmer who was remarkably easily offended by the slightest thing one said, and I had to be extremely careful with her in order to keep my job. So, such a thing exists.

Comment: no offense, but I'd question whether I'd want to work in an environment where I must carefully watch what I say to that extent.  But cultures can and do vary alot around the world.

Comment: No offense taken. But jobs are tight. I work with what I can get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$badwords = "fuc";
$replacebad = "****"; 
$string = $_POST['something']; 
$filtered = str_ireplace($badwords, $replacebad, "$string");
echo $filtered;
?>
```

something like this ?
Edit:
sorry I didn't noticed the php5 part ..

Comment: No, obviously not. The list is easily seen by programmers, unencoded.